# Hiding "Series1" from chart legend when values are null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I have a chart that needs to show all months of the year even if they do not contain any data. Problem is, my legend displays these null records as "Series1" on my legend.

Is it possible to get rid of the "Series1" from the legend? I've tried creating a custom legend to hide any values that are null but I'm running into issues.

Here's the syntax I've tried:
`=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Type.Value), NOTHING, Fields!Type.Value)`

Here is the data that is coming over. Any NULL values for the column "Type" are showing on the legend as "Series1" while the other values show as they should

```
MonthNumber MonthName   Type
1           Jan         NULL
2           Feb         Value1
2           Feb         Value3
3           Mar         Value2
3           Mar         Value1
4           Apr         NULL
5           May         NULL
6           Jun         NULL
7           Jul         Value3
7           Jul         Value1
```

Comment: Are the values representing the months without data coming over, for example, if month 8 has no data is a record with 8 coming over with null values or is there no record with 8?

Comment: Ross, I've edited my question and added in test data to show what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: On that label, try placing a " " space for empty. Series.Label=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Type.Value), " ", Fields!Type.Value). This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Hi, @RossBush how do you apply that expression when the legend is generated at run time? i.e. it just has illustrative values in legend.

Answer (score 0):

finally found a solution in Visual Studio 2019.
Using "Chart Data" context menu, choose right-click context menu of Values series being used (box next to sigma sign). 
Choose "Series Properties..."
Choose Legend then the function against "Do not show this series in a Legend".
i.e.

> Series Properties > Legend > Do not show this series in a Legend >> Function
>    -> Expression:

Then use the following expression;

```
=IIF(Fields!Type.Value IS NOTHING, true, false)
```